# Cassandra Column families list using JMX

Tags: cassandra

I want to retrieve column families list from JMX approach in cassandra. I am using JMX approach to retrieve data from cassandra. I am able to retrieve keyspaces list but there is no any predefined mbean to get list of column families which belongs to this keyspaces.
I want to know is there any way to get list of this column families specific to keyspaces using JMX or JAVA.

Comment: What version? the mbean names have changed over time

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildecard character (*) in object name to get list of column families in specified keyspace e.g.:

```
JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect( url, env );
            MBeanServerConnection mbsc = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();    
ObjectName oName = new ObjectName( "org.apache.cassandra.db:type=ColumnFamilies,keyspace=your_keyspace,columnfamily=*" );
        Set<ObjectName> names = mbsc.queryNames( oName, null);
        Set<ObjectInstance> mbeans = mbsc.queryMBeans( oName, null );
```

So `name` will contain jmx names for all column failies in the keyspace and `mbeans` will contain MBeans for all column families in the keyspace.

More dateails about name patterns in [JMX documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/ObjectName.html)